# Creating a 10 second delay using ISR in TIMER1 of atmega328p

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmega

I'm trying to create a 10 second delay using TIMER1(16 bit) in atmega328p, I don't know if the delay has been created or not because it takes longer duration than 10 seconds and expected output( which is to create pwm waves) is not obtained. Here I have created a 1second delay and looped it 10 times, TIMER0 is used for creating pwm waves.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include "interrupt.h"
#define SET_BIT(PORT,BIT) PORT |= (1<<BIT)
#define CLR_BIT(PORT,BIT) PORT &= ~(1<<BIT)

struct {
  volatile unsigned int BIT: 1;
}
FLAG_TIMER;

void timer_configuration()  //16 bit timer
{
  TCCR1A = 0x00; // Normal mode of operation
  TCNT1 = 0xC2F8;
  TCCR1B |= ((1 << CS10) | (1 << CS12));
  TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS11); //101
  sei(); // Global interrupt
}
void timer_on()
{
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE1);
}
void pwm_configuration()    //TIMER0 - 8 bit
{
    TCCR0A |= ((1<<WGM00) | (1<<WGM01));    //setting it to fast PWM mode
    TCCR0A |= (1<<COM0A1);
    TCCR0A &= ~(1<<COM0A0);
    TCNT0 = 0x00;
    TCCR0B |= ((1<<CS00) | (1<<CS02)); //Prescaler setting 1024
    TCCR0B &= ~(1<<CS01);
    sei();
}


ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) 
{
  static unsigned int counter;
  counter++;
    if(counter >= 10)
    {
        
        FLAG_TIMER.BIT=1;
        counter = 0;
        TCNT1 = 0xC2F8;
        TIMSK &= ~(1<< TOIE1);
    }
    else
    {
        FLAG_TIMER.BIT=0;
    }
  }
int main(void)
{
SET_BIT(DDRD,PD6); //CRO
timer_configuration();
pwm_configuration();
while(1)
{
timer_on();

    if(FLAG_TIMER.BIT == 1)
    {
        OCR0A = 128; //50% dutycycle
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually we use timer to produce small delay (nanoseconds or microseconds). I would rather use system ticks to produce this range of delay. What is your question ?

Comment: What's the obscure BIT struct good for? Why can't you use a bool? Calling `timer_on();` from the main loop looks strange, are you sure it doesn't reset some flag?

Comment: Also, why not write self-documenting code `DDRD |= CRO;` or `DDRD |= 1u << CRO;`

Comment: Try simplifying the code and testing the different parts of it before combining them.  Are you able to write code that just turns on the PWM output right away?  Are you able to move that PWM code into the TIMER1_OVF_vect ISR and still make it run (just to prove that you are getting that ISR to run)?

Comment: @Lundin This is not my complete project, I'm struggling with the timer overflow part so i separated that from the original code, I have to start the overflow in one specific event to create a 10sec delay, so instead of specifying timer_on() during timer_configuration(), I gave it separtely.  I don't know if this is a correct approach, any suggestions pls.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to simplify and test the code.

Comment: @GabrielT I have to create a 10sec delay so I tried to create a 1 sec delay(count starts from 49912 and ends at 65535) and loop it 10times, since I have used normal operation mode of TIMER1, I thought this would be appropriate, another approach is to create 3 timer overflow( each counts 0 to 65535) and at-last loop TCNT1 should reach 880 for 10sec delay, I chose the first method. Is this right way or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You set the counter to 49912 on initialisation and increment your count when it overflows, but it will then start from 0, so if 15624 counts = 1 second, then your counter will increment to 10 after 15624 + 9 x 2<sup>16</sup> counts or about 38.75 seconds.

Move the `TCNT1 = 0xC2F8;` line in the ISR:

```
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) 
{
  static unsigned int counter;

  TCNT1 = 0xC2F8;

  counter++;
  if(counter >= 10)
  {
    FLAG_TIMER.BIT=1;
    counter = 0;
    TIMSK &= ~(1<< TOIE1);
  }
  else
  {
    FLAG_TIMER.BIT=0;
  }
}
```

I am not familiar with ATmega, but I cannot believe that is an appropriate way to use the timer.  Normally you'd up-count to a compare value with auto reset to zero, or down-count from an auto reload value to zero and let the hardware reload the counter.